# Conjectures that are false for very large numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, computer-algebra-systems, computer-arithmetic

Hi I would like to teach my students about false conjectures and computer approaches to them. I need references and/or direct examples of statements of the form $(\forall n \geq n_0)P (n)$ where $P$ is a relatively simple property (e.g. of elementary number theory) such that the smallest number $m$ for which $P (m) $ is false is ridiculously bigger than $n_0$.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15444/examples-of-eventual-counterexamples

Answer (score 1):

A popular example is [Mertens Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture): $M(n)=\sum _{{1\leq k\leq n}}\mu (k)$
where $\mu(k)$ is the Möbius function; the Mertens conjecture is that for all $n > 1$,

$$
\left|M(n)\right|<{\sqrt  {n}}.$$